# What does this symbol that looks like a stylized "P" mean in each of Hajime no Ippo's matches?

Tags: japanese-language, hajime-no-ippo

What does the symbol resembling a stylized "P" in each of *Hajime no Ippo*'s matches mean? Is it a Japanese symbol for cheering maybe?

[image: Ippo chapter 612]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbol that looks like "P" is actually **"[ア](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_(kana))", a katakana for letter "A"**.

According to Jisho, ["Aaa"](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%82%E3%83%BC%E3%81%82) could mean:

> Aah!; Ooh!; Oh No!; Oh Boy!; expression of despair, resignation, boredom, disgust, etc.​

though it could also mean yelling, shouting, cheering (depending on the situation).

Comment: I suspect in these cases they would best be translated as "Woah!"